# returning promises for sequential runing child processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, spawn

I am trying to spawn a child process and have its results in a Promise.
The child process can not run multiple times at the same time.

I am wrapping node.js's [child_process.spawn()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) in a Promise.
The promise fulfills when the process exits successful and rejects if otherwise.
Requests com in at different times sometimes one sometimes multiple. I need to execute the same command for every request maybe even multiple times (with different or possibly the same options) to fulfill the requests. But the command will lock up if run in parallel. So it can not be run without making sure it exited beforehand.

Maybe i need them to queue up?

I can't wrap my head around how to do this in JavaScript / Typescript. Busy waiting is obviously no god idea, but i hope it explains what I want to do here.

```
export class RunThingy{

private busy: boolean;

constructor() {
  this.busy = false;
}

private run(options: string[]): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let stdout: string = '';
    let stderr: string = '';
    while (!this.busy) {             //Problem
      this.busy = true;
      let process: ChildProcess = spawn('processName', options); 
      process.stdout.on('data', (contents) => { stdout += contents; });
      process.stderr.on('data', (contents) => { stderr += contents; });
      process
        .on('error', reject)
        .on('close', function (code) {
          if (code === 0) {
            resolve(stdout);
          } else {
            reject(stderr);
          }
          this.buisy = false;        //Problem
        });
    }
  });
}
```

Edit: renamed `command[]` to `options[]`

Comment: Maybe use `.finally(()=> this.buisy = false;)` on the promise ?

Comment: I don't see how this might help here. There is no try catch block. What exactly do you suggest?

Comment: `.finally` is not the same as `finally`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A promise can be rejected or resolved once. Each process must be wrapped in a promise. Here is a proposition:

```
export class RunThingy {
    private curCommand: Promise<string> | null

    private run(options: string[]): Promise<string> {
        let next: Promise<string>
        if (this.curCommand) {
            next = this.curCommand.then(
                () => runCommand(options), // the next command will be started after
                () => runCommand(options)  // the current will be resolved or rejected
            )
        } else
            next = runCommand(options)
        next = next.then(stdout => {
            if (next === this.curCommand) // if this is the last command
                this.curCommand = null    // then forget the current command
            return stdout                 // return the command value
        }, err => {
            if (next === this.curCommand) // if this is the last command
                this.curCommand = null    // then forget the current command
            throw err                     // throw again the error
        })
        this.curCommand = next
        return this.curCommand
    }
}

function runCommand(options: string[]): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let stdout = '';
        let stderr = '';
        let process: ChildProcess = spawn('processName', options);
        process.stdout.on('data', (contents) => { stdout += contents; });
        process.stderr.on('data', (contents) => { stderr += contents; });
        process
            .on('error', reject)
            .on('close', function (code) {
                if (code === 0) {
                    resolve(stdout);
                } else {
                    reject(new Error(stderr));
                }
            });
    });
}
```

In the method `run`, we check if there is a current command. The new command will be started after the current command will be resolved or rejected.

Comment: I don't understand how this solution prevents the process from being run in parallel? Sorry I should have called the "commands" better as "options"

Comment: The "options" are fine. But i don't get how i queue up multiple calls of the process.

Comment: @J.Doe Oh. I don't understand what are your several processes? Why don't you run the command just once? What is the purpose of your loop `while`? Or you want to execute several time the same command with the same options?

Comment: @J.Doe Or you want to call `RunThingy.run` several time in your code, while to ensure that only one process run at a time?

Comment: Yes exactly. Requests com in at different times sometimes one sometimes multiple. I need to execute the same command for every request maybe even multiple times (with different or possibly the same options) to fulfill the requests. But the command will lock up if run in parallel. So it can not be run without making sure it exited beforehand.

Comment: @J.Doe Please note I just edited, again. I added a test `if (next === this.curCommand)` before to set `this.curCommand` to `null`. It's required. Otherwise, if two commands are waiting, when the first will end the variable `this.curCommand` will be unset.